# Downgrading Python Breaks Conda

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, conda

I have Python 3.7 installed, which apparently doesn't support Keras. 
When I try to download Keras using conda, Python gets downgraded to 3.6.8 and Conda stops working.

When I try to run Conda, I get the following error,

```
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

I also tried to downgrade Python directly by running,

```
conda install python==3.6
```

and I got the same behaviour.

Could anyone please help in solving this frustrating issue?

Comment: Keras works fine in Python 3.7, I use it every day.

Comment: How did you install Keras in Python 3.7? When I do `conda install keras`, it automatically downgrades Python to 3.6.8

Comment: By not using anaconda, and installing keras using pip.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda is not stable in python 3.7 but you need to create environment for installing keras using conda

```
conda create -n yourEnvName python
```

Now activate that environment using following command

```
activate yourEnvName
```

Next install tensorflow and keras for it using pip command

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install keras
```

Comment: The command should be `conda activate yourEnvName`. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "Anaconda is not stable in python 3.7"

Comment: Could you please clarify what you meant by "Anaconda is not stable in python 3.7"? I figured that I needed to create an environment for Python 3.6, but I want to understand what's causing this strange behavior.

Comment: I mean tenaorflow and keras is not stable with python 3.7